# Double quotes being added to precompiled Ember templates

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Here is the template in question:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                My Company
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {{#each page in pages}}
                <li {{bind-attr class="page.isActive:active"}}><a href="javascript:undefined" {{action 'navigate' page}}>{{page.name}}</a></li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left hidden-sm" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <button {{action "search"}} class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>{{#link-to 'cart' class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"}}{{/link-to}}</li>
                {{#if user}}
                <li>{{user}}</li>
                {{else}}
                <li>{{#link-to 'login'}}Sign In{{/link-to}}</li>
                <li>{{#link-to 'register'}}Register{{/link-to}}</li>
                {{/if}}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
{{outlet}}
<div class="container">
    <hr />
    <footer class="footer">
        © My Company
    </footer>
</div>
```

I compiled them using the ember-template-compiler.js file that came with my version of Ember (1.9.1)

For some reason, these quotes are being added around the nav in the markup and it's messing up the layout of my page.

[image]

I thought it might be related to a [whitespace issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4305) with ember 1.9, but I tried saving the files with Unix style endings and it didn't help.

Does anyone have any clue what might be causing this issue?

Comment: can you show us what's before and after the template in question? How do you render it?

Comment: the template is the application template, so it's the root of my app.

Comment: Ember renders the template when I load my website from any route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because Visual Studio would save my .hbs files in UTF8 with BOM (with signature) which adds a bunch of hidden characters to the beginning of the file.

I saved them without signature and it works perfectly now. No more empty strings, and my layout is how I expect it to be.